# Missing RAM on an HP ENVY h8-1414?

Tags: memory

I have an [HP ENVY h8-1414](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03517389&prodSeriesId=5295996) and it has four [8GB dimms](http://www.corsair.com/vengeance-8gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9b.html) in it.

[image: Corsair CMZ8GX3M2A1600C98]

The machine should support 32GB of RAM according to the website but only 16 GB of it is being picked up.

I've looked at the settings in CPU-Z and here is what they look like:
[image: Slot #1]
(it's all the same kind of RAM)

What do I need to do to get the additional 16GB of RAM that aren't being recognized?

Comment: Do you see the 32GB in the BIOS/UEFI? If yes, which OS do you use? The Home Editions of Windows are limited to 16GB RAM (Vista/7 Home Premium)

Comment: are all 4 chips of the same size and speed? have you tried reseating the ram? I would contact HP. on my last laptop (dv910us) I needed an updated bois from them before the new ram would be recognized, despite being well within the limitations of the boards specs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I think you have hit the nail on the head. The max mem on home prem is 16GB. CPU - Z is picking up that that particular stick is representing 4GB.

Comment: @magicandre1981 No actually I don't see it in the bios.  Maybe I do need to update the bios

Comment: make sure the memory remapping function is enabled in the BIOS. Is the RAM compatible with your board? Have you checked the memory list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module shown in your list is a 4GB module, if you have 4 of those modules then you only have 16GB.

What you have bought is two 8GB dual-channel **kits**.  The kit means that it will provide a total of 8GB.

From [Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/vengeance-8gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9.html)

> **Product Description**
>
> High-performance 8GB Vengeance Dual Channel Kit, 1600MHz, 9-9-9-24,
>   1.5V Key Features
>
> **Package Contents**
>
> ***Two 4GB memory modules***

-=Original Answer=-

It may well be that you have a memory limited edition of Windows and may need to upgrade to a higher edition to use the extra memory.  Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit has a limit of 16 GB. Windows 8 (standard) is limited to 128GB

From [Windows Physical Memory Limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7):

```
Version                 Limit on X86       Limit on X64
Windows 7 Ultimate      4 GB                192 GB
Windows 7 Enterprise    4 GB                192 GB
Windows 7 Professional  4 GB                192 GB
Windows 7 Home Premium  4 GB                16 GB
Windows 7 Home Basic    4 GB                8 GB
Windows 7 Starter       2 GB                N/A
```

Comment: I now notice that written on it is 8GB (2x4GB)...I didn't buy this, I was given it, they told me these were 8GB Dimms and when I looked at the part that says 8GB on the Dimm I stopped reading.  Never seen RAM labeled that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the link provided for the RAM modules is correct, you don't have four 8GB Dimms, but four 4GB dimms.
The websites says, that it is an 8 GB Kit, consisting of two 4GB modules.
That would also fit CPU-Z reading of the SPD data from the dimm.